# what is the recommended batch size when deleting Firestore documents in a collection?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

so I want to delete all documents in a collection using admin SDK, the code below is taken from [official documentation in here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#node.js_2)

```
async function deleteCollection(db, collectionPath, batchSize) {
  const collectionRef = db.collection(collectionPath);
  const query = collectionRef.orderBy('__name__').limit(batchSize);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    deleteQueryBatch(db, query, resolve).catch(reject);
  });
}

async function deleteQueryBatch(db, query, resolve) {
  const snapshot = await query.get();

  const batchSize = snapshot.size;
  if (batchSize === 0) {
    // When there are no documents left, we are done
    resolve();
    return;
  }

  // Delete documents in a batch
  const batch = db.batch();
  snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
    batch.delete(doc.ref);
  });
  await batch.commit();

  // Recurse on the next process tick, to avoid
  // exploding the stack.
  process.nextTick(() => {
    deleteQueryBatch(db, query, resolve);
  });
}
```

as you can see, I need to provide a batchSize, which is a number, so what size that I should provide? say for example I have 100.000 documents in a collection.

because from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions), there is also a limitation from Firestore

> Maximum writes per second per database : 10,000 (up to 10 MiB per
> second)

so how to decide the batch size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `batchSize` variable is used to define a `Query` with the `limit()` method. This `Query` is passed to the `deleteQueryBatch()` method where it is executed and where, based on the query result, a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) is populated with some delete operations.

Since a batched write **can contain up to 500 operations**, the maximum value you can assign to `batchSize` is 500.

PS: I know that I am not exactly answering your question which is more about the **recommended** batch size but, since 500 is the documented limit for a batched size, you should not encounter any problem with this limit, unless maybe if you delete lexicographically close documents, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#high_read_write_and_delete_rates_to_a_narrow_document_range) in the doc.

Comment: Thanks Renaud, 500 is clearly the max batch size, but I think will try 100 docs as my batch size to comply the "500/50/5" rule  (max 500 operations per second) https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#ramping_up_traffic